# iOS 7 Background fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am currently working on one iOS app, in which I am using     `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];`. According to the docs I have implemented in this way .

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSLog(@"Launched in background %d", UIApplicationStateBackground == application.applicationState);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
    i =0;

    return YES;
}


-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"Fetch started");
    ++i;    

    // Set up Local Notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    localNotification.fireDate = now;

    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.alertBody = @"BG Mode";
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = i;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    NSLog(@"Fetch completed");
}
```

My issue is I have tried to debug it to know how frequently this method is calling . I didn't get any clarification. I have tested with timeinterval 60 seconds, but that is also not working . Please give me any ideas or suggestions . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, you've also set the UIBackgroundModes in Info.plist as per Apple's documentation ...

> This property has no effect for apps that do not have the UIBackgroundModes key with the fetch value in its Info.plist file.